# Javascript, Chrome Extension development, XMLHttpRequest Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, permissions, google-chrome-extension

Am having a slightly confusing problem with this extension (although it might just be my inexperience)
in my manifest file I have:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://mafre.com/","http://eee.se/","http://ilaafire.net/","notifications","tabs"
```

And i am using this code to send an XML request:

```
var http = false;
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();

function replace() 
{


            http.open("GET", "http://www.mafre.com/proj/test.php"+getquerystring(), true);
            http.onreadystatechange=function() 
            {

            if(http.readyState < 4) {show_wait_gif();}
                else if(http.readyState == 4) 
                {
                    updatepage( http.responseText);

                }
            }
          http.send(null);
 }
```

which my script on the other end is getting the data... but when I need to get the response Chrome is throwing this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mafre.com/proj/test.php?w=rn@ee.se. Origin 
chrome-extension://kjggpdimdloblnddfbnodggchjpalihb is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Why is that? I have already given it permission to interact with the domain so why cannot I get the response even though it is sending the query?

The response that I should get back into my page is something like "email accepted, thanks!1"

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you should wildcard permission URLs, also `www.` is a different domain:

```
"http://mafre.com/*",
"http://www.mafre.com/*",

"http://eee.se/*",
"http://www.eee.se/*",

"http://ilaafire.net/*",
"http://www.ilaafire.net/*",

"notifications",
"tabs"
```

Currently you only have access to exactly `http://mafre.com/`.

Comment: @Ryan: It does for me. Did you reload the extension?

Comment: @Ryan: I uploaded the most trivial version and it works: http://www.2shared.com/file/850FaUZF/origin.html.

Comment: ARRRGH! My stupid fault, i had two manifest files open and was editing the wrong one (serious DUH! moment). Your solution works perfectly and sorry for the above. Wish i could vote up your help x1000, and another x10000 for my stupidity. Thanks again!